# Print combobox value in label

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am just started to use Python. I have some combobox and I want to print the selected value on a label. For me is difficult because I use dictionary.

Can someone help me to print combobox value on a label?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk


class NewCBox(ttk.Combobox):

    def __init__(self, master, dictionary, *args, **kw):
        ttk.Combobox.__init__(self, master, values=sorted(list(dictionary.keys())),
                              state='readonly', *args, **kw)
        self.dictionary = dictionary

        # purely for testing purposes
        self.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', self.selected)

    def value(self):
        return self.dictionary[self.get()]

    def selected(self, event):  # Just to test
        print((self.value()))


class NewCBox1(ttk.Combobox):

    def __init__(self, master, dictionary, *args, **kw):
        ttk.Combobox.__init__(self, master, values=sorted(list(dictionary.keys())),
                              state='readonly', *args, **kw)
        self.dictionary = dictionary
        # purely for testing purposes
        self.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', self.selected)

    def value(self):
        return self.dictionary[self.get()]

    def selected(self, event):  # Just to test
        print((self.value()))


lookup = {'Arkitekt': 'A', 'Geoteknik': 'B',
          'Ingeniør Anlæg': 'C', 'Procesanlæg': 'D'}

documentcode = {'Aftaler': 'AGR', 'Analyse': 'ANA',
                'Myndigheder': 'AUT', 'Sagsbasis': 'BAS'}

root = Tk()

newcb = NewCBox(root, lookup)
newcb.pack()

newcb1 = NewCBox1(root, documentcode)
newcb1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Do you want to print the values (corresponding to the key selected) or the keys of the dictionary? Do you want to print in a `tkinter.Label` that is for example under the combobox or what?

Comment: I want to get value from the selected combobox shown on a label...example when I select `'Arkitekt' from NewCombox, the program should print A on that label, and when I choose a value like 'Aftaler' from NewCombox1 should program print something like 'A AGR' on the same label... Yes on a tkinder label

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually don't need 2 classes, but just one. If you observe well your code, you will notice that both classes are pretty much the same, but with different dictionaries. So, you can simply instantiate 2 objects from the same class by passing to the `__init__` value 2 different dictionaries.

If you want a `Label` whose text changes whenever you select something from your comboboxes, I would not inherite from a `ttk.Combobox` but from a `Frame`, so that you can customize your class with a `ttk.Combobox` and a `Label`.

To set the text of a `Label` you can use the method [`config(...)`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.config-method) common to all widgets.

See my example below (and if you have further questions ask as a comment):

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class LabeledCombobox(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master, dictionary, *args, **kw):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, *args, **kw)
        self.dictionary = dictionary

        self.combo = ttk.Combobox(self, values=sorted(list(dictionary.keys())),
                                  state='readonly')
        self.combo.current(0)
        self.combo.pack(fill="both")
        self.combo.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', self.on_selection)

        self.label = tk.Label(self, text=self.value())
        self.label.pack(fill="both", expand=True)


    def value(self):
        return self.dictionary[self.combo.get()]

    def on_selection(self, event=None):  # Just to test
        self.label.config(text=self.value())


lookup = {'Arkitekt': 'A', 'Geoteknik': 'B',
          'Ingeniør Anlæg': 'C', 'Procesanlæg': 'D'}

documentcode = {'Aftaler': 'AGR', 'Analyse': 'ANA',
                'Myndigheder': 'AUT', 'Sagsbasis': 'BAS'}


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Labeled comboboxes")

    combo1 = LabeledCombobox(root, lookup, bd=1, relief="groove")
    combo1.pack(side="left", padx=(2, 2), pady=5)
    combo2 = LabeledCombobox(root, documentcode, bd=1, relief="groove")
    combo2.pack(side="right", padx=(2, 2), pady=5)

    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I appreciate your explanation . But what if I want to print or display the selected value ( as your sample) on one label. So I can generate a name like A_ANA , A_AGR or B_AGR etc. ?      because later I'll use the generated value on the label to rename files.

I will later make a rename function that uses the genereted value (genereted value = combination of values selected from combobox) to rename files as an example ..... A_ANA.pdf, C_AGR.doc OR A_AGR.pdf

Neither I do not know how the code for the rename funcktion will look like if you could help me with that also I will be grateful.

Comment: I want one label that contains values, of selected values from combo1 and combo2. and not 2 separate label